# Формирование счётчика при использовании confirm

Tags: javascript, функции, счетчики

Как поставить условие, чтобы при нажатии ОК в окне confirm счётчик приплюсовывал 1, а при нажатии ОТМЕНА приплюсовывался 0.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function(){
  var counter = 0;
  var oldConfirm = window.confirm;
  window.confirm = function(message) {
    var result = oldConfirm(message);
    if (result)
      counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    return result;
  };
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="confirm('Do you confirm?');">Click</button>
```